# Customize the Knit button with source

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

The rmarkdown's [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html) , recommends customising knitr button with custom script called via source.

This is the YAML of `.Rmd` file

```
---
knit: (function(input, ...) {
    # my custom commands
  })
---
```

**My approach**

I have created a `custom-function.R` script in the same directory and tried to call via source.

**`custom-function.R`**

```
(function(input, ...) {
        # my custom commands
      })
```

**`.Rmd` file**

```
---
knit: source("custom-function.R")
---
```

The error is -

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "(function(input, ...) { system(paste0("source("custom-function.R"
Execution halted
```

Looks like there is syntax error. I checked the [documentation of `source`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/source) and syntax looks fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the documentation you linked to mentions using the `source` function at all. It might have changed since you asked the question, but right now it only mentions two options:

- "write the source code of the function directly in the `knit` field"
- "put the function elsewhere (e.g., in an R package) and call the function in the knit field"

I guess your situation is a little bit of both. Here is what you can do:

In `custom-function.R` name the function (no need for parentheses here):

```r
custom_knit <- function(input, ...) {
  # your custom commands
  # don't forget to actually call `rmarkdown::render()`
}
```

Then, in your `.rmd` file, write another function that first sources the script above and then calls the `custom_knit` function. Here, you *do* need parentheses. Also, "if the source code has multiple lines, you have to indent all lines (except the first line) by at least two spaces" (from the `bookdown` docs you linked to).

```yaml
knit: (function(input, ...) {
    source("custom-function.R");
    custom_knit(input, ...)
  })
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was caught up with some deadlines. Thanks for your help. It works perfect. There is a minor change needed in your second function though. There should be `;` after `source("custom-function.R")`. Once again, thanks :)

Comment: @kbc, you are right, I've added the semicolon to the answer.